# Bash match digit

Tags: bash, sed, match

Let's say I have a file named output1

How to match just digits form 3th to 5th position so to have 'tpu'?

Thanks.

Comment: `a=output1; ${a%??}` but this will remove just the last two

Comment: By "digit" I think you mean "character". "ptu" is not a substring of "outpu1". Do you want to extract 3rd to 5th or do you want to look for files with these characters in these positions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash:

```
i=output1
echo ${i:2:3}
```

Comment: Thanks. And to match until the end not just until 3?